# SSIS Script Component Write to Variable

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

This is with SQL 2005.

I have a script component inside a Data Flow Task. I would like to read from the input columns and write the data to a global user variable.

I've set my input columns and added my global user variable as a ReadWriteVariable to the script component properties.

Here is my code, I'm just trying to alter the value of the global user variable here, but its not working. When I write out the value of the variable in another task it still has its default value:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent
    Dim updateSQL As String

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim vars As IDTSVariables90

        VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("SQL_ATTR_Update", vars)
        vars("SQL_ATTR_Update").Value = "Test"
        vars.Unlock()
    End Sub


    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        'updateSQL = Row.ITMID + Row.PRCCAT
    End Sub

End Class
```

I have also tried with no luck:

```
Me.ReadWriteVariables("SQL_ATTR_Update").Value = "Test"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out.

From MS:

> In Script component code, you use
>   typed accessor properties to access
>   certain package features such as
>   variables and connection managers.
>
> The PreExecute method can access only
>   read-only variables. The PostExecute
>   method can access both read-only and
>   read/write variables.
>
> For more information about these
>   methods, see Coding and Debugging the
>   Script Component.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136031.aspx

It looks like Dts is only available in Script Task.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent
    Dim updateSQL As String


    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
        Me.ReadWriteVariables("SQL_ATTR_Update").Value = "Test"
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        'updateSQL = Row.ITMID + Row.PRCCAT
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: in SSIS 2008, you cannot declare a function called PostExecute with Overrides.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you could do it:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-variables-in-script.html

Comment: This is correct answer. This becomes very important when you use Script Component as Source.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Dts.Variables("SQL_ATTR_Update").Value = "Test"
```

And SQL_ATTR_Update needs to be a global variable and listed in your ReadWriteVariables for that script task.

Comment: When I add Dts it says "Name 'Dts' is not Declared."

I can use Dts fine in a Script Task though, but not a component.

Comment: Dts.Variables is only exposed in a control flow. In a data flow you have to you the this.Variables field.